# Creating NSDictionary with Initial Name to Sort

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I'm trying to merge the code from [this link](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-index-list-uitableview/) into my own application while using my own dictionary. I have had several problems, however.

My code produces this kind of dictionary (because I'm using a web service to get this data from a MySQL database):

```
{audiences = ({
            name = ABDUL;
            id = 1;
        },{
            name = ELSA;
            id = 2;
        },...etc)}
```

However, I want a dictionary like this:

```
audiences = @{@"B" : @[@"Bear", @"Black Swan", @"Buffalo"],
              @"C" : @[@"Camel", @"Cockatoo"],
              @"D" : @[@"Dog", @"Donkey"]};
```

Which, in my case, would appear like this:

```
audience = @{@"A":@[@"Abdul"],
             @"E":@[@"Elsa"]};
```

To summarize my problems:
1) How can I create an `NSDictionary` using only the `name`s (no `id`)?
2) The dictionary including initial in it

Thanks for your help, I'm a newbie in Xcode and Objective-C, so please forgive me if I'm asking a noob question. Also, please bear with my bad English. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What would you expect to happen to empty name strings?

Comment: @CrimsonChris: Hmm... it should show nothing, just the initial title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, your initial data structure received from the web service is (re-expressed in Cocoa):

```
NSDictionary* data = @{ @"audiences" : @[
                                          @{ @"name" : @"ABDUL",
                                             @"id" : @1 },
                                          @{ @"name" : @"ELSA",
                                             @"id" : @2 },
                                        ] };
```

You can build the data structure you describe like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary* audience = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (NSDictionary* person in data[@"audiences"])
{
    NSString* name = person[@"name"];
    if (![name length])
        continue;

    NSRange range = [name rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex:0];
    NSString* key = [[name substringWithRange:range] uppercaseString];
    NSMutableArray* list = audience[key];
    if (!list)
    {
        list = [NSMutableArray array];
        [audience setObject:list forKey:key];
    }
    [list addObject:name];
}
```

Comment: this code works just like what i need ^^ Thanks a lot for your help, @KenThomases

Comment: i add image url in the database and now i need the output to be A:{@[name],@[imageurl]} Can you help, what i need to do? I tried to modify your code but not working my way -_-" @KenThomases

Comment: I recommend that you ask a new question for this. Put in a clear description of the new source data and also of exactly what you want the resulting data structure to look like.

Comment: Please help me @KenThomases this is [the link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25521785/add-images-from-mysql-database-on-sorted-uitableviewcell) to my new question

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you don't want the initials to be case sensitive.

```
NSArray *audiences = @[
                        @{ @"name" : @"ABDUL", @"id" : @1 },
                        @{ @"name" : @"ELSA", @"id" : @2 },
                        @{ @"name" : @"erik erikson", @"id" : @3 },
                        @{ @"name" : @"Leeroy Jenkins", @"id" : @-1 },
                        @{ @"name" : @"", @"id" : @4 },
                      ];

NSMutableDictionary *audienceMembersByInitial = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (NSDictionary *audienceMember in audiences) {
    NSString *name = audienceMember[@"name"];
    if (name.length > 0) {
        NSString *initial = [[name substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString];
        NSArray *audienceMembersWithInitial = audienceMembersByInitial[initial] ?: @[];
        audienceMembersByInitial[initial] = [audienceMembersWithInitial arrayByAddingObject:name];
    }
}
return [audienceMembersByInitial copy];
```

Output is...

```
@{
  @"A" : @[ @"ABDUL" ],
  @"E" : @[ @"ELSA", @"erik erikson" ],
  @"L" : @[ @"Leeroy Jenkins" ],
};
```

Comment: Jinx. ;) I recommend avoiding `-substringToIndex:` because it could split surrogate pairs or composed characters. Also, no reason to copy the array when returning it. Since nothing else holds it, it won't be mutated behind the back of the caller who receives it.

Comment: Never would have guessed anybody else was jumping on this question :). You could make a similar argument against using the non localized `uppercaseString`. I'm gonna say both is outside the scope of this trivial example.

Comment: Non-localized `-uppercaseString` is appropriate for an index, which is what this appears to be. Splitting strings is not an esoteric or "niche" thing to get right. It is not just in exotic or foreign locales that the distinction becomes significant.