# add images from MySQL database on sorted UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uitableview, nsdictionary

i'm new to Xcode and Objective-c and i wanna make a contact list which sorted alphabetically also have images in it. Please check [this](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-index-list-uitableview/) for reference.

This code tells me everything i need but the problem is i use name and images from MySQL instead of hardcoded like that.

I have imported the data to NSDictionary and this is the result:

```
audiences=({name="ABDUL",id="1",photo="asd.png"},{name="ABDUL",id="2",photo="qwe.png"});
```

What i need to do to add the name and photo (only that 2 items, without id) to UITableViewCell?
I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25519024/creating-nsdictionary-with-initial-name-to-sort/25519229#25519229) code before but only show the sorted name and i don't have any idea how to call the images.

This is how i parse the name so i can grab it for the list:

```
NSMutableDictionary* audict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
               for (NSDictionary* person in dataDict[@"audience"]){
                  NSString* name = person[@"name"];
                  if (![name length])
                     continue;
                  NSRange range = [name rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex:0];
                  NSString* key = [[name substringWithRange:range] uppercaseString];
                  NSMutableArray* list = audict[key];
                  if (!list){
                     list = [NSMutableArray array];
                     [audict setObject:list forKey:key];
                  }
                  [list addObject:name];

                  audiences=audict;
                  audienceSectionTitles = [[audiences allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
                  audienceIndexTitles = @[@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E", @"F", @"G", @"H", @"I", @"J", @"K", @"L", @"M", @"N", @"O", @"P", @"Q", @"R", @"S", @"T", @"U", @"V", @"W", @"X", @"Y", @"Z"];
```

This is where the code executed

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   // Return the number of rows in the section.
   NSString *sectionTitle = [audienceSectionTitles objectAtIndex:section];
   NSArray *sectionAudience = [audiences objectForKey:sectionTitle];
   return [sectionAudience count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return [audienceSectionTitles objectAtIndex:section];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

   // Configure the cell...
   NSString *sectionTitle = [audienceSectionTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
   NSArray *sectionAudience = [audiences objectForKey:sectionTitle];
   NSString *audience = [sectionAudience objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   UIFont *myFont = [ UIFont fontWithName: @"Helvetica" size: 12.0 ];
   cell.textLabel.font  = myFont;
   cell.textLabel.text = audience;
   cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self getImageFilename:audience]];
   return cell;
}

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
   return audienceIndexTitles;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
   return [audienceSectionTitles indexOfObject:title];
}
```

And here where i need to put my the image strings:

```
- (NSString *)getImageFilename:(NSString *)audience
{
   NSString *imageFilename = @"profile.png";

   return imageFilename;
}
```

Please i need your help ^^;

Answer (score 0):

Are the images on your database? MySQl you mean, are you using sqlite or Core Data?
This is the code for a simple select in sqlite:

`const unsigned char *myBlob = sqlite3_column_blob(sqlite3_stmt *, column);`
`if(myBlob != NULL){`
`value = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char *)myBlob];`
`}`

Comment: No. I use php web service to get the data from MySQL Database, I'm not using either sqlite or CoreData. But, i don't think this is the problem because i already grab all data and put it in NSDictionary. This is the dictionary showed {audiences = ({
            name = ABDUL;
            id = 1;
            photo = 0192038409.jpg
        },{
            name = ELSA;
            id = 2;
            photo = 647263846.jpg
        },...etc)} @DavidBemerguy

Comment: You mean the dictionary you retrieve from the ws brings you the name of the image? Instead of its data?

Comment: No. The ws brings the above data. Then i create another dictionary which only have the name (i followed the tutorial) then the user want the images also added in the list. But i don't know how to add the image based on their name or id. Pls help @DavidBemerguy